# How to efficiently test for the existence of a list of tables in Postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have an application that *CREATE-IF-NOT_EXISTs* a long list of tables when it first connects.

Performance is acceptable on the corporate LAN, since it stays connected for a long time between restarts, but it is painfully slow with the added latency on the WAN.

Rather than iterate through a loop of individual creates, I would like to issue *one* SQL query that will efficiently tell me whether all required tables are present, so I can bypass the optional setup step.

I've found a number of answers on StackOverflow for how to do with with a single table, but I don't know how to expand those examples to use a list of table names.

Can anybody suggest how to efficiently tell me if all the named tables in a list are present? (the query should fail if any of the listed tables does not exist, and succeed otherwise.)

(No discussion on whether creating/checking for tables on each connect is a good idea, please - I can't control this part of the design.)

Comment: What if there's at least 1 table missing, what needs to be done? create the one missing table or the whole thing?

Comment: @PatB - if at least one table is missing, it likely means the 'init' code never ran, (or errored out part-way for some reason) and so I would just go ahead and run the old create-of-not-exists loop. It's not pretty, but I can live with a slow initial connect [I can force the init to happen on the LAN] -- all I'm trying to avoid here is for every single connect to have to delay again for as long as the initial connect/setup operation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The names of existing tables are stored in the `relname` column of the `pg_class` table. You can issue a ‘where in’ query for all the required tables and make sure you get the same amount of rows back.

```
select rn = 3 from ( 
  select count(*) rn from pg_class 
  where relname in ('table1','table2','tablen')
  and relkind = 'r'
) t1
```

If you can create a table of your required names then a `not exists` query might be cleaner because you don’t have to keep track of the count.

```
select exists (
    select 1 from required_tables rt
    where not exists (
        select 1 from pg_class pc where pc.relname = rt.table_name
        and relkind = 'r'
    )
)
```

Comment: This looks pretty good, but pg_class seems to have a bunch of other stuff listed besides tables (e.g. indexes?) -- how do I tighten this up to eliminate false-positives?

Comment: Why use `pg_class` instead of `pg_tables`?

Comment: @jpmc26 `pg_tables` works too. I prefer `pg_class` because it isn't a view

Comment: I don't understand. Why do you prefer a table over a view? I checked, and the query plan is *exactly* the same regardless of which one you use. So I don't see the benefit, whereas using the view provides improved readability and simplicity by abstracting implementation details of `pg_class` out of your query.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're already going to have to modify the code to make it skip the current create, use this query to fetch the list of tables:

```
SELECT schemaname||'.'||tablename FROM pg_tables
```

Then you just compare this result set to your known list of tables in code. (You can use set difference or loop over a list or whatever your app's language provides.) I prefer this since it keeps my query simple, meaning I don't have to fight with an ORM or other client to get a complex query right. Instead, I'm just fetching some straightforward data, and then the logic is in code.

You can filter down to the schemas you're actually using if you want:

```
SELECT schemaname||'.'||tablename FROM pg_tables WHERE schemaname IN ('public', 'mycustomschema')
```